# Apache CXF - The given SOAPAction does not match an operation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I started working again on a project I started a few years ago (code available here: http://code.google.com/p/mipnp/).
It's a UPnP mediaserver that can stream media to an xbox 360.

For the SOAP part in UPnP I used Apache CXF.
With CXF version 2.4.8 everything works like it should.
But whenever I try to update to CXF version 2.4.9 (or newer) I get the following exception:

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1}MediaReceiverRegistrarService#{urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1}IsAuthorized has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: The given SOAPAction urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1#IsAuthorized does not match an operation.
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapActionInInterceptor$SoapActionInAttemptTwoInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapActionInInterceptor.java:188)
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapActionInInterceptor$SoapActionInAttemptTwoInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapActionInInterceptor.java:162)
  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:209)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:191)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)
  at com.googlecode.mipnp.upnp.ServerHeaderFilter.doFilter(ServerHeaderFilter.java:60)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is what the SOAP request looks like:

```
POST /control/x_ms_mediareceiverregistrar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Xbox/2.0.16202.0 UPnP/1.0 Xbox/2.0.16202.0
Connection: Keep-alive
Host:192.168.1.11:34331
SOAPACTION: "urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1#IsAuthorized"
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 304

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <s:Body>
      <u:IsAuthorized xmlns:u="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1">
         <DeviceID></DeviceID>
      </u:IsAuthorized>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the 'DeviceID' parameter not being in the 'u' namespace.
But I can't seem to find a fix or workaround.

This is how i'm creating the web service:

```
/*
 * MediaReceiverRegistrar.java
 * Created on Jun 30, 2011, 4:00:45 PM
 */
package com.googlecode.mipnp.mediaserver;

import com.googlecode.mipnp.upnp.ServiceImpl;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;

@WebService(
        portName="X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar",
        targetNamespace="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1")
public class MediaReceiverRegistrar extends ServiceImpl {

    @WebMethod(operationName="IsAuthorized")
    public void isAuthorized(
            @WebParam(name="DeviceID")
            String deviceId,
            @WebParam(name="Result", mode=WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<Integer> result) {

        result.value = 1;
    }
}
```

(You can find the complete code [here](http://code.google.com/p/mipnp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mipnp/mediaserver/MediaReceiverRegistrar.java))

And this is how the wsdl looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="MediaReceiverRegistrarService" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="IsAuthorized" type="tns:IsAuthorized"/>
<xs:element name="IsAuthorizedResponse" type="tns:IsAuthorizedResponse"/>
<xs:element name="IsValidated" type="tns:IsValidated"/>
<xs:element name="IsValidatedResponse" type="tns:IsValidatedResponse"/>
<xs:element name="RegisterDevice" type="tns:RegisterDevice"/>
<xs:element name="RegisterDeviceResponse" type="tns:RegisterDeviceResponse"/>
<xs:element name="getIdAsUrn" type="tns:getIdAsUrn"/>
<xs:element name="getIdAsUrnResponse" type="tns:getIdAsUrnResponse"/>
<xs:element name="getTypeAsUrn" type="tns:getTypeAsUrn"/>
<xs:element name="getTypeAsUrnResponse" type="tns:getTypeAsUrnResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="getTypeAsUrn">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getTypeAsUrnResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="IsValidated">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DeviceID" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="IsValidatedResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Result" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="IsAuthorized">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DeviceID" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="IsAuthorizedResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Result" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getIdAsUrn">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getIdAsUrnResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="RegisterDevice">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistrationReqMsg" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="RegisterDeviceResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistrationRespMsg" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="RegisterDeviceResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:RegisterDeviceResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getTypeAsUrnResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getTypeAsUrnResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IsValidatedResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:IsValidatedResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getIdAsUrnResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getIdAsUrnResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getIdAsUrn">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getIdAsUrn" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getTypeAsUrn">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getTypeAsUrn" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RegisterDevice">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:RegisterDevice" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IsValidated">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:IsValidated" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IsAuthorizedResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:IsAuthorizedResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IsAuthorized">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:IsAuthorized" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="MediaReceiverRegistrar">
    <wsdl:operation name="getTypeAsUrn">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getTypeAsUrn" name="getTypeAsUrn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getTypeAsUrnResponse" name="getTypeAsUrnResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="IsValidated">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IsValidated" name="IsValidated">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IsValidatedResponse" name="IsValidatedResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="IsAuthorized">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:IsAuthorized" name="IsAuthorized">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:IsAuthorizedResponse" name="IsAuthorizedResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getIdAsUrn">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getIdAsUrn" name="getIdAsUrn">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getIdAsUrnResponse" name="getIdAsUrnResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RegisterDevice">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RegisterDevice" name="RegisterDevice">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RegisterDeviceResponse" name="RegisterDeviceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="MediaReceiverRegistrarServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:MediaReceiverRegistrar">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getTypeAsUrn">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getTypeAsUrn">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getTypeAsUrnResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="IsValidated">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="IsValidated">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="IsValidatedResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="IsAuthorized">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="IsAuthorized">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="IsAuthorizedResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getIdAsUrn">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getIdAsUrn">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getIdAsUrnResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RegisterDevice">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="RegisterDevice">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="RegisterDeviceResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="MediaReceiverRegistrarService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:MediaReceiverRegistrarServiceSoapBinding" name="X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.11:54802/control/x_ms_mediareceiverregistrar"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I tried adding the following line, because I read somewhere that the security measures went up since CXF version 2.4.9:

```
@EndpointProperty(key="soap.no.validate.parts", value="true")
```

But that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

THe issue is that the wsdl has:

```
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
```

but the request is sending:

```
SOAPACTION: "urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1#IsAuthorized"
```

There are a couple options:

1)  You could update the WSDL to include that string as the soapAction and regenerate all the code and such.

2) You could write a CXF interceptor that removes the soapAction from the request headers (or sets it to "" like the wsdl states)

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up adding the action element to the WebMethod annotation like this:
`    @WebMethod(
        operationName="IsAuthorized",
        action="urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1#IsAuthorized")
    public void isAuthorized(
        @WebParam(name="DeviceID")
        String deviceId,
        @WebParam(name="Result", mode=WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Integer> result) {

        result.value = 1;
    }`

Comment: Would it be possible to write a CXF interceptor on the server side? If so any idea how it would work with J-boss's bundled CXF? Attempts to configure such an interceptor using "cxf.xml" and "jbossws-cxf.xml" have not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem long time agos, I tried to add

`@EndpointProperty(key="soap.no.validate.parts", value="true")`

but that doesn't help, in my case I don't own the web service that i was consuming and the response of that web service doesn't follow the rules of the WSDL, so i ended changing the response with and interceptor like this one:

/*Interceptor class */

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyInterceptor.class);

public MyInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    logger.info("TCP-InterceptandoMensaje");
    message.put(Message.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    InputStream is = message.getContent(InputStream.class);

    if(is!=null){
        CachedOutputStream bos = new CachedOutputStream();
        try{
            IOUtils.copy(is, bos);
            String soapMessage = new String(bos.getBytes());
            logger.info("-------------------------------------------");
            logger.info("TCP-SoapMsgRecibido[" + soapMessage +"]");
            logger.info("-------------------------------------------");
            bos.flush();
            message.setContent(InputStream.class, is);

            is.close();
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(removeBody(soapMessage).getBytes());
            message.setContent(InputStream.class, inputStream);
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String removeBody(String msg) {
    StringBuffer soapMsg = new StringBuffer();
    if (msg.contains("Reason")) {
        if (msg.contains("TarjetaCreditoConsultaDetalle_Req")) {
            soapMsg.append(msg.substring(0, msg.indexOf("<NS1:Body>")));
            soapMsg.append("<NS1:Body>");
            soapMsg.append("<NS2:TarjetaCreditoConsultaDetalle_Resp xmlns:NS2=\"http://www.bi.com.gt/esb/services/TarjetaCredito\">");
            soapMsg.append("<InfoTrx>");
            soapMsg.append("<IdTrx>000000000000000000000000</IdTrx>");
            soapMsg.append("<Canal>000</Canal>");
            soapMsg.append("<PaisOperacion>000</PaisOperacion>");
            soapMsg.append("<BancoOperacion>0</BancoOperacion>");
            soapMsg.append("<PaisDestino>000</PaisDestino>");
            soapMsg.append("<BancoDestino>0</BancoDestino>");
            soapMsg.append("<FechaTrx>00000000</FechaTrx>");
            soapMsg.append("<HoraTrx>000000</HoraTrx>");
            soapMsg.append("<IdCliente/>");
            soapMsg.append("<CodOpWeb/>");
            soapMsg.append("<CodEmpresa/>");
            soapMsg.append("<TotPags>000</TotPags>");
            soapMsg.append("<CodRetorno>000</CodRetorno>");
            soapMsg.append("</InfoTrx>");
            soapMsg.append("<Datos>");
            soapMsg.append("<Producto>0</Producto>");
            soapMsg.append("<NumProducto>0000000000000000</NumProducto>");
            soapMsg.append("<NombreCuenta> </NombreCuenta>");
            soapMsg.append("<Moneda>USD</Moneda>");
            soapMsg.append("<Estado>00000000</Estado>");
            soapMsg.append("<SaldoLocal>0.00</SaldoLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<SaldoDispLocal>0.00</SaldoDispLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<SaldoInter>0.00</SaldoInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<SaldoDispInter>0.00</SaldoDispInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<DirCorrespond> </DirCorrespond>");
            soapMsg.append("<FechaCorte>00000000</FechaCorte>");
            soapMsg.append("<FechaProxPago>00000000</FechaProxPago>");
            soapMsg.append("<SobreGiroAutLocal>0.00</SobreGiroAutLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<SobreGiroAutInter>0.00</SobreGiroAutInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<FecUltCambioEstado>00000000</FecUltCambioEstado>");
            soapMsg.append("<FecUltMov>00000000</FecUltMov>");
            soapMsg.append("<FecUltAbono>00000000</FecUltAbono>");
            soapMsg.append("<PagoMinLocal>0.00</PagoMinLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<PagoContLocal>0.00</PagoContLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<PagoMinInter>0.00</PagoMinInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<PagoContInter>0.00</PagoContInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<LimiteAutLocal>0.00</LimiteAutLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<LimiteAutInter>0.00</LimiteAutInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<Seguros>");
            soapMsg.append("<SegTCSalva>1</SegTCSalva>");
            soapMsg.append("<SegCobInt/>");
            soapMsg.append("<SegVida/>");
            soapMsg.append("<SegFourSeason/>");
            soapMsg.append("</Seguros>");
            soapMsg.append("<MontoTrxLocalDeb>0.00</MontoTrxLocalDeb>");
            soapMsg.append("<MontoTrxLocalCred>0.00</MontoTrxLocalCred>");
            soapMsg.append("<SaldoMaxVenc>0.00</SaldoMaxVenc>");
            soapMsg.append("<MontoExtrafAutLocal>0.00</MontoExtrafAutLocal>");
            soapMsg.append("<MontoExtrafAutInter>0.00</MontoExtrafAutInter>");
            soapMsg.append("<MontoTrxInterDeb>0.00</MontoTrxInterDeb>");
            soapMsg.append("<MontoTrxInterCred>0.00</MontoTrxInterCred>");
            soapMsg.append("</Datos>");
            soapMsg.append("</NS2:TarjetaCreditoConsultaDetalle_Resp>");
            soapMsg.append("</NS1:Body>");
            soapMsg.append("</NS1:Envelope>");            
        } else
            soapMsg.append(msg);
    } else
        soapMsg.append(msg);
    logger.info("EditedSoapMsg["+soapMsg+"]");
    return soapMsg.toString();
}`
```

My spring-config looks like:

```
<bean id="tcPaymentServiceInterceptor" class="com.foo.bar.ws.interceptors.TcPaymentServiceInterceptor"/>

<bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus">
    <property name="inInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="tcPaymentServiceInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I hope this help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found the solution in http://forum.openkm.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12494

The Web service was created in java using simple @WebService and @WebParam annotations.

It seems to be a problem in Apache CXF library from 2.5.1 to 2.6.14. The second solution of Daniel Kulp is the easy way.

In ksoap2 (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar) library for Android you can use this way:

```
HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE("http://10.0.2.2:8080/server-ws/actionServerWS?wsdl");
transporte.call("", envelope);
```

Hope this